# Brownie pm is attempting to load .env from installed package

Tags: brownie

Environment information

```
brownie Version: 1.18.1
Python Version: 3.8.12
OS: osx
```

What was wrong?

My tests now fail after adding a `.env` file to my project and specifying that file in  `brownie-config.yml`.
They fail when attempting to setup a fixture that utilises OpenZeppelin's ERC20 contract.

Here is the fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def oz(pm):
    project = pm("OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0/")
    return project
```

Brownie config:

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable@4.5.0
dotenv: .env
compiler:
  solc:
    version: 0.8.9
    optimizer:
      enabled: true
      runs: 200
    remappings:
      - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0"
      - "@openzeppelin-upgradeable=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable@4.5.0"`
```

And the error:

```
    @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
    def oz(pm):
>       project = pm("OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0/")
E       ValueError: Dotenv specified in config but not found at path: ~/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0/.env
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue. I resolved it by removing the "dotenv: .env" setting from `brownie-config.yaml` and instead importing `load_dotenv` from `dotenv` explicitly in the test file.

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def usdc_token(pm):
    ERC20 = pm("OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0").ERC20
    return ERC20.at("0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! It's a nice idea, but unfortunately this doesn't help if you've got env variables within your brownie-config... something like:

    wallets:
      from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}

which is quite a common occurrance

Comment: I've actually opened a PR on the brownie github that ensures the .env file exists when installing new packages https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/pull/1504

Please take a look, comment, etc so that it gets a bit more attention!